# How can i change the number of product to 4 in grid view to appear in one line in bazar theme woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to accomplish the above without any luck...any suugestions would be appretiated.

here is a link to my page : http://umsi.me/uniikmedia/?post_type=product

i have added this code to my functions.php file :

```
   add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
   if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
   function loop_columns() {
   return 4; // 3 products per row
   }        
   }
```

I also tried disabling the shop-sidebar.php file.

I was able to make it work on all desktop browsers but on mobile browers it wasn't loading up the image in the right size, but keeping the width of 1200px.

Here is the css i used to make it work

```
 html body.archive div.bg-shadow div#wrapper.container div#primary.sidebar-left   div.container div.row div#content-shop.span9 ul.products {
  width: 1200px;
  float: right;

 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have issue on Items not display properly or what?

Comment: Yes the items are not loading properly on mobile devices it looks like its streched on the screen but it works fine on the desktop browsers. let me know if you need more info.

Comment: ok i figured it out...thanks